# Strategies to deal with a sadistic dominant person whose compliance you need?

Tags: negotiation

I am in a situation where I have to provide my services and products to a health care insurance companies in a specific area (prosthetics).

A certain health care insurance company hired a product manager who himself provided prosthetics to handicapped people for a few years, then decided it's not for him and that he would provide his knowledge to companies instead so that they don't blindly accept / pay any offer that prosthetics providers offer.

This product manager also gets a provision for anything the company does not have to pay. Additionally, he thinks that basic prosthetics are sufficient, and last it's a personal pleasure for him to be in a power position. He calls us and other prosthetics suppliers regularly and demands cheaper prices, otherwise he would involve another supplier. We can barely survive because he keeps prices at an absolute minimum.

There is a law that forces health care insurance companies to negotiate prices with us. The health care insurance has to look at our proposal and decide if they accept it or not.

I thought about offering him the lowest prices and demanding being called for counter-offers (where other companies already did all the diagnostics, and we would simply offer the product for less money, as this is what he is known for doing already).

However, I suspect a dominant and sadistic nature of his character who not only wants the lowest prices but also a kind of humiliation, and my offer would not suit him as he still needs this constant battle and proof of his dominance.

Also, he already negotiated prices so low with other parties that they finally gave up and don't work with this company anymore.

What might be strategies to deal with such parties?

Comment: Just say "no" to his "negotiation" tactics.  If you are not able to make a profit on your product when selling to this person, then sell elsewhere.

Comment: The most obvious strategy is "don't deal with him". Seems your competitors have already done the same, at which point he'll have to come back with a better offer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't workplace issue, it's about relations between customer and supplier.

Comment: Why don't you hire a better marketing manager to deal with him?

Comment: most proposals that "demand" things get binned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decline to work with him as commenters have offered, or, assuming you don't want to give up just yet, I suggest flattering him. Play to his ego by telling him how great he is at his job and that he has really pushed your margin to the edge. Embellish this (I can't offer more specific examples because I'm not in your situation). Lay it on thick. Do this before failing to meet your target.